# Maatwebsite Laravel-Excel UTF8 problem in CSV export

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel

When I use "->export('xls')", the result is ok, but if I use "->export('csv')", the UTF8 charcters come with encode problem.
Exemple: Waister GuimarÃ£es,"waisters@gmail.com"

i use `"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",`

Answer (score 2):

Try edit **config/excel.php** : from `'use_bom' => false` to `'use_bom' => true`

maybe this will help you

Comment: Emm maybe try to upgrade the package to ~3.1.0 , it looks like 2 is not more supported

Comment: Making this edit to the config file was the solution for me as well. I just wanna point out that if you can't find it, you have to run `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider" --tag=config` (source: [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html#installation-2)).

Answer (score 0):

You try using: `header("content-type:application/csv;charset=UTF-8");` in your code

OR You can use package `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet`

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

May be help you.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem:

I changed the value: 'use_bom'=>false to 'use_bom'=>true